# CSS reset to each browser's default view, not to the same view

Tags: css

Are there any stylesheets which make, say, input view like default in each browser? 
I mean not the same view in every browser, but still default view in each of them.

UPD. Of course it's the case when i have some parent css which i need to override back to default view, especially for particular element.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use a CSS reset stylesheet and every browser will use its own default rendering settings until you start to override them.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser pretty much has its own standard stylesheet with custom css for common elements such as paragraphs, body element, and all the rest of the elements which it supports. Each browsers stylesheet isn't exactly the same, so for example while one browser sets padding on the body, another will set margin on the body element.

If you rely on a css reset, you basically attempt to gain more control by explicitly setting certain properties to a consistent value, such as margin and padding on all elements to 0 ( which isn't preferred for form controls ).